# Run a job on every node of a Quartz JDBC backed cluster

Tags: spring, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I have a cluster of two Tomcat nodes running a Spring web application. I have Quartz configured with a `RAMJobStore` and am switching to `LocalDataSourceJobStore` to provide clustering so that each job runs at most on one node. Most of the jobs including some new jobs operate on the database and benefit from this feature.

Unfortunatley I have one job that operates on data in RAM and there is no synchronisation set up. The simplest solution I can see is for that one job to simply run on all of the nodes without co-ordination, as it did with `RAMJobStore`.

**Is there a way to configure a job to run on all the nodes under LocalDataSourceJobStore?**

The precise timing is not critical, but the jobs must run on every node every 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I think you could configure 2 Schedulers, one for your clustered jobs and one for your RAM job store. If using spring you would then config like this.

for the clustered store

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
    ...... configure your clustered triggers here 
</bean>
```

and then for the RAM Store set up another scheduler with a different quartz.properties file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz_ram.properties" />
    ...... configure your RAM store triggers here 
</bean>
```

Comment: Tried it. There seems to be some state shared via statics or thread locals and you get errors.